# Size of content of a frame

Tags: javascript

I have a frame with a width of, say, 200 pixels. The content inside that frame is bigger than 200 px. How do I find the size of the content?

I can scroll the content using,

```
<iframe id="frame_name" src="bla bla"></iframe>
t = document.getElementById ("frame_name");
t.contentWindow.scrollTo(x,y);
```

but I don't know when to stop since I don't know the width of the content. Please, no jquery, thanks.

Comment: Is the `iframe` `src`on the same domain?

Comment: yes, everything's in the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome and Safari, you can use `t.contentWindow.document.width` and `t.contentWindow.document.height`.

In Firefox, IE and Safari, you can use `t.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth` and `t.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight`.

Comment: t.contentWindow.document.width is undefined...(I'm testing it in firefox 21.0)

Comment: Updated answer to include Firefox

Comment: Thanks Borre! If it's not asking too much, what are the property names for IE and Safari? Thanks again =)

Comment: The Firefox solution works in IE, I cannot test Safari as I do not have a Mac but I'm assuming the Chrome solution will work there as well

Comment: In safari, both  contentWindow.document.width and contentDocument.body.scrollWidth seem to work.